# Table loads twice when view is loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, icloud

I have a table which loads data from iCloud. When I go back from a detailed view to the **UITableView**.

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

the table contains the data already obviously from the previous load and then it loads again once it has the fresh data from iCloud. should I clear the table before segue to detail view or is there a way of not having the data load twice. It's not a big problem but for user experience, it looks like the table loads and then loads again.

Comment: Is it adding objects into array twice??

Comment: Where do you load your data? Add some code related.

Comment: Hi @Anand it doesn't load the array twice, the table still contains the data from before the detail view segue. It just appears to load again when the view pops back.

Comment: Use the debugger. Probably in `viewWillAppear` the data are fetched and appended to the data source array. To avoid duplicates empty the array before the data fetch.

Answer (score 1):

Better you create BOOL

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isViewExist;
```

and use this at your table reload place

```
    if(self.isViewExist){
        self.isViewExist = YES; 
    }else{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
```